# How to add data to firebase realtime database on android using Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

When I upload data to the fire base realtime database it uploads everything perfectly but when I register a new user the previous users data gets deleted every time a new user is created

this is the code I use to upload the data:

```
private fun uploadUserDataToDatabase(email: String) {

    var uid = mAuth.currentUser?.uid
    var user = User(email)

    myRef.child(uid!!).setValue(user)

}
```

This is what the data base looks like after a user has registered:

[image]

This is what the database looks like after a nother user registers:

[image]

How do i get it to not delete the previous user everytime a new user is registered?

if i change it to

```
myRef.child(uid!!).push.setValue(user)
```

it uploads the data twice and looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I am not an expert in `firebase-realtime-database`, but in `cloud-firestore` there is a function `.add()` which does not override the old value. So I would try `.addValue()` instead of `.setValue()`

Comment: That last screenshot looks as expect when you call `push()`. If tht is not what you want, edit your question to show the JSON you want to get.

Comment: In the first two screenshots, there are two different UIDs, I cannot see any reason why one of them is deleted unless you are especially doing it in your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
myRef.child(uid!!).push().setValue(user)
```

Comment: if i change it to that it uploads the data twice. i've added it to the question so you can see

Comment: no because as soon as i register another user id deletes the previous users data

Comment: u added to ur question thats not deleting

Comment: i dont understand

Comment: what u want then?

Comment: when a user registers, there data should get uploaded to the database. and when another user registers, their data should also get uploaded to the database without deleting the firsts users data

Comment: so at the moment there is only one user in the database which is the user that has most recently registered. but i want all users data to stay in the database

Comment: but when u use push it adds new entries

Comment: Which is why i don't now why its not working because a new user registers the previous user is deleted

Comment: as per last screenshot, user is not getting deleted

Comment: yes it is, it deleted the previous user and add the same user twice thats why he emails are the same